# Regex expression to replace strings in between "<" and ">"

Tags: java, regex

I tried the below expression. But the issue is, regex takes the string in between the first "<" and the last ">".

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = scanner.nextLine();
str = str.replaceAll("\\<[^\\(]*\\>", "kk");
```

> Input: hello <'david> who <'the heck> are you
>
> Output I am getting: hello kk are you
>
> Output I want: hello kk who kk are you

What regex should I use to replace strings between "<" and ">" individually, instead of as a whole (first "<" and last ">") ?

Comment: `<[^>}*>` is what your asking.

Comment: Are you sure you are not expecting the output to be "hello kk who kk are you"?

Comment: @Hawkings have a look over here. https://ideone.com/Fh8XCi

Comment: @tarun14110 I mean that you probably want the output to be: hello kk who kk are you, right?

Comment: @Hawkings oh yes, my bad.

Comment: What is the point of ``\\`` before `<` and `>`? These are not regex metacharacters. More info: http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special

Comment: Anyway what you are doing here looks like preventing some HTML injection (or other specific task which you are not telling us). If that is true it is example of [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Solution for this most likely already exist in technology you are using, but to point it out we need to know what really you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Pshemo I have updated the question. Please have a look. I just want regex expression to replace all strings between "<" and ">".

Comment: This `first "<" and last ">" ` is not what you need. If that's the case, you'd get "herelo `<weorld>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>`". So, you can see that choosing words in explanation's are important. If that's _not_ what you mean, correct that, and make it a starting point.

Comment: Why are you excluding `(` in this part `[^\\(]`, when you want to exclude `>`? Try `"<[^>]*>"`, and result is `hello kk who kk are you`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the pattern `<.*?>`.

If you just use `.*`, which is a greedy pattern, it consumes all characters (matches) between the first `<` and the last `>` in your input.

Make it less greedy by using the `?` character

Here is what you need:

```
String character = "<.*?>";
String str = "hello <'david> who <'the heck> are you";
str = str.replaceAll(character, "kk");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

> hello kk who kk are you

Reference:

Take a look at this to know more about [greedy and lazy *regex*es](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap).

---

Hope this helps!